# Force integers of a given size with bin?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm playing around with bitwise operators to get more comfortable with using them.

The problem I'm having is that since Python has infinite width integers, it's difficult to see the actual results of certain operations.

```
>>> bin(0b00000001 & 0b11110111)
0b1
```

I'd like to see `0b00000001` instead.

Is there a good way to experiment with these operators with fixed-size integers in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `format()` function:

```
print(format(0b00000001 & 0b11110111, '#010b'))
```

**Output**

```
0b00000001
```

The string parameter to the `format()` function specifies the format of the output. The `#` makes the output include the `0b` prefix, and the `10` indicates that the entire output should be 10 characters. The `0` preceding the `10` enforces zero left-padding in the `10` output characters. You can remove the hash if you want to remove the `0b` prefix.

Comment: Technically the first `0` in `010` specifies zero-padding rather than space-padding, and the `10` sets the field width. Good answer!

Comment: @holdenweb to be brutally honest I haven't been into the docs on the `format()` function. This answer is just my understanding from using it in practice! I will take a look at the docs and update to reflect your comment.

Comment: No real need for an update - your answer is good, and the solution works. I was kind of nitpicking because I recently had to document formatting for the third edition of the _Python in a Nutshell_ reference - though I'd have written it as `"#010b".format(0b00000001 & 0b11110111)`.

Comment: What holdenweb said. It's more normal Python syntax (& slightly more efficient) to call the `str.format` method than to call the `format` built-in function.